# Close antd popover and open a child antd modal in the same function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-props, react-state

I have an Antd popover, that by clicking a button inside its content, opens a modal.
I want to close the popover when the modal opens.

When I tried just passing the popover visibility state setter down to the modal as a prop, there was a problem. There was some kind of "collision" between the state of the modal and the passed down prop state of the popover:

[Collision CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-pass-visibility-to-child-modal-with-collision-6336h)

I did find a workaround - creating the modal state variables in the parent component (the popover) and passing them down to the modal using props:

[Working CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-pass-visibility-to-child-modal-hlw7s)

First of all, you can notice that the modal isn't closing at it supposed to - there's no nice smooth animation minimizing it, it just suddenly disappears. For reference, you can look [here](https://ant.design/components/modal/) to see how it should look like when closing.

So my question is - why did this collision happen? Is there a better way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: what about this solution ? if its okay tell me to post as an answer
https://codesandbox.io/s/popover-pass-visibility-to-child-modal-forked-z565b?file=/index.js

Comment: because the modal is originated from popover that in the future destroyed , the popup animation does not work , I think you must separate modal from content of popover to prevent this situation

Comment: This is a great solution!
But the other part of my question remained unanswered:
Why did this "collision" happen in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This collision happens because in show modal handler you set visibility of popover to false and hide it and ant-popover-hidden class add to it's div element so anything inside it would not display like Modal however you show modal but because of its parent it couldn't visible, so I think You must separate modal from the popover content and place it somewhere beside them like this:

```
const Test = () => {
  const [isSharePopoverVisible, setIsSharePopoverVisible] = useState(false);
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const handlePopoverVisibleChange = () => {
    setIsSharePopoverVisible(!isSharePopoverVisible);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
    setIsSharePopoverVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Popover
        trigger="click"
        title="Test"
        visible={isSharePopoverVisible}
        onVisibleChange={handlePopoverVisibleChange}
        content={
          <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
            Open Modal
          </Button>
        }
      >
        <Button>Test</Button>
      </Popover>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <p>Some contents...</p>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```